# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater, setcontentview

```
package com.example.provafragment;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button firstFragment, secondFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // get the reference of Button's
        firstFragment=(Button) findViewById(R.id.firstFragment);
        secondFragment=(Button) findViewById(R.id.secondFragment);

        // perform setOnClickListener event on First Button
        firstFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // load First Fragment
                loadFragment(new FirstFragment());
            }
        });
        // perform setOnClickListener event on Second Button
        secondFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // load Second Fragment
                loadFragment(new SecondFragment());
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // create a FragmentManager
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        // create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the Fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fm.beginTransaction();
        // replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
    }
}
```

This is the main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/button_background_color"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/button_background_color"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml layout

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.provafragment, PID: 6588
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.provafragment/com.example.provafragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.provafragment:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.provafragment:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.provafragment:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.provafragment:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.provafragment:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.provafragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 15 to dimension: type=0x4
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:787)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5555)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:254)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:250)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:246)
            ... 30 more
```

This is the debug console. It crash in setcontenview but my xml seems correct.
Into the other two file i set the view like a very simple oncreate function
I use androidx and if you need more let me know. I'm trying everything to make it work. I already made "clean project" and "rebuild project"
Thank you for your help

Comment: try to invalidate cache . from what I see at your xml, looks all fine.

Comment: the error is not in your activity but maybe in the xml of your fragment

Comment: Nothing changed by invalidating cache.
My other activity xml file haven't got red allert but if you want I can post the code

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I forgot dp after the number in dimen xml file. check that.